# Migrate user credentials ( User Name,Password) from SQL DB to Azure AD B2C

Tags: sql, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to migrate users info (username, password) from SQL DB to Azure AD B2C. In Azure AD there is way to migrate user credentials using AD Connect. But AD B2C does not supports AD Connect. Can you please help is there any other alternative ways to migrate users credentials?

Comment: Have tried anything ?

Comment: Trying with Graph API, will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the Graph API. The exact way depends on whether you have access to the user's passwords, or just a one-way hash of them.

The steps necessary are documented in the [AAD B2C User migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration).

There is no existing tool for it like AD Connect. You have to develop your own, but the documentation has a sample app that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks !. But it helps to migrate only clear text passwords. In my case, the user passwords are stored in the form of "salted + hashed". Is there anyway to migrate hashed passwords to Azure AD B2C through Graph API or others ??